# How to find closest match from list in R

Tags: r

I have a list of numbers and would like to find which is the next highest compared to each number in a `data.frame`. I have:

```
list <- c(3,6,9,12)
X <- c(1:10)
df <- data.frame(X)
```

And I would like to add a variable to `df` being the next highest number in the `list`. i.e:

```
X   Y
1   3
2   3
3   3
4   6
5   6
6   6
7   9
8   9
9   9
10  12
```

I've tried:

```
df$Y <- which.min(abs(list-df$X))
```

but that gives an error message and would just get the closest value from the list, not the next above.

Answer (score 2):

Another approach is to use `findInterval`:

```
df$Y <- list[findInterval(X, list, left.open=TRUE) + 1]

> df
    X  Y
1   1  3
2   2  3
3   3  3
4   4  6
5   5  6
6   6  6
7   7  9
8   8  9
9   9  9
10 10 12
```

Answer (score 1):

You could do this...

```
df$Y <- sapply(df$X, function(x) min(list[list>=x]))

df
    X  Y
1   1  3
2   2  3
3   3  3
4   4  6
5   5  6
6   6  6
7   7  9
8   8  9
9   9  9
10 10 12
```